What is the meaning of 'someone/something is a quality side'?
So in the book I ran into the following sentence 'Arsenal are a quality side and still contenders for a place in the top four...'
Does it mean that they are trying to do everything the best way possible? I haven't found any information on the Internet:(
Thanks in advance!

Have you tried looking up "quality" (adjective) in a dictionary? The meanings you get there should be clear enough. Specific questions about football tactics are off-topic, but surely most people know the difference between a good and a bad team.
